# Printing the output of a script to a window in python

Tags: python-2.7, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to create a GUI for the analyzeMFT python program. So far this is what i have

```
#!/usr/bin/python
  # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import analyzeMFT


class Example(Frame):
  
    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
         
        self.parent = parent
        self.filename = ""        
        self.initUI()
        
        
    def initUI(self):
      
        self.parent.title("Mtf Analyzer")
        
        #initializing and configuring menubar

        menubar = Menu(self.parent)
        self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
        
        fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Open file", command=self.fileOpen)
        fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
        menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)


        #specify grid row and column spaces
       
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

        self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
        self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
        self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)
        
        lbl = Label(self, text="File Name")
        lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        filename_area = Entry(self)
        filename_area.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=3, 
            padx=5)

        analize_button = Button(self, text="Analize",  command=self.processFile)
        analize_button.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=5)
        
        area = Text(self)
        area.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
            padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)



        #configure the raw output view
        

    def onExit(self):
        self.quit()

    #this function selects and opens the file to analize
    def fileOpen(self):
        from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

        Tk().withdraw() 
        self.filename = askopenfilename() 

        #populate the filename field
       


    #do the processing of the file obtained. Populate the file NAME entry or
    #send the filename to the analyzeMFT.py
    def processFile(self):
        filei = "-f "+self.filename
        arguments = [filei, '-o '+self.filename+' .csv']
        analyzeMFT.main(arguments)

    #get and set methods for the entry field
    def get(self):
        return self.filename_area.get()

    def set(self, value):
        filename_area.set(value)


def main():
  
    root = Tk()
    root.geometry("250x150+300+300")
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code creates a gui that i can chose a file to analyze using the analyzeMFT program. There are two problems.

1.analyzeMFT is meant to be run on command line. I am not able to pass the file name I get from the GUI to the analyzeMFT.py Here are the contents of analyzeMFT.py

```
    #!/usr/bin/python

try:
    from analyzemft import mftsession 
except:
    from .analyzemft import mftsession

def main(): 
    session = mftsession.MftSession()
    session.mft_options()
    session.open_files()
    session.process_mft_file()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Next, when i run the analyzerMFT in cmd and enable debug mode, it prints every detail on the screen. How can I direct that out to a window i have shown below
[image]

I want it somehow to look like this
[image]

Sorry if the explanation is very long. I've been working on it for days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using print like you would normally use to display results to the console you can use `insert()` on your text box.

EDIT:

First change:

```
area = Text(self)
area.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
            padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)
```

To:

```
self.area = Text(self)
self.area.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
            padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)
```

This way your text box is set up as a class attribute that we can use.

Then use:

```
self.area.delete(1.0, "end") # to clear text box 
self.area.insert("end", your_output variable or string) # to insert content
```

Comment: Thanks @sierra Mountain. Let me try that.

Comment: Thanks @sierra Mountain. Let me try that.

Comment: @samuelkungu: Sorry I had to update my answer. Some typos and a little more explanation on what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks @sierra. I vote +1 because it has helped. Now the problem comes moving the value to print from one script to the script with GUI. Let me open another thread instead. Thanks again, I appreciate

Comment: @samuelkungu: In order to work with the text box in your Example class from outside of that class you will need to make sure the text box is set up as a class attribute with `self.` once that is done you can do something like `app.area.insert("end", your_output variable or string)`. That should do the job.

Comment: please check this question i have posted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45282561/python-tkinter-method-for-printing-not-working-after-being-called-from-another