# Python Tkinter- method for printing not working after being called from another script

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have a class called app.py within that class there's a method called `print_raw_records_screen` here's the part of the class and the method

```
app.py


#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *
import os
import mftsession


class Example(Frame):

def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)   
     
    self.parent = parent
    self.filename = ""        
    self.initUI()

#defining a function that that receives the raw records from the mftsession.py and print it to the screen
#this script will be called by the mftsession.py in 
#process_mftfile()
def print_raw_records_screen(self,records):
    self.area.delete(1.0, "end")
    self.area.insert('1.0',records)
    
    
def initUI(self):
  
    self.parent.title("Mtf Analyzer")
    
    #initializing and configuring menubar

    menubar = Menu(self.parent)
    self.parent.config(menu=menubar)
    
    fileMenu = Menu(menubar)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Open file", command=self.fileOpen)
    fileMenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=self.onExit)
    menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=fileMenu)


    #specify grid row and column spaces
   
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)

    self.columnconfigure(1, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(3, pad=7)
    self.rowconfigure(3, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(5, pad=7)
    
    lbl = Label(self, text="File Name")
    lbl.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

    self.filename_area = Entry(self)
    self.filename_area.grid(row=1, column=1, columnspan=5, padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)

    analize_button = Button(self, text="Analize",  command=self.processFile)
    analize_button.grid(row=1, column=6, padx=5)
    
    self.area = Text(self)
    self.area.grid(row=2, column=1, columnspan=2, rowspan=4, 
        padx=5, sticky=E+W+S+N)



    #configure the raw output view
    

def onExit(self):
    self.quit()

#this function selects and opens the file to analize
def fileOpen(self):
    from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

    Tk().withdraw() 
    self.filename = askopenfilename() 

    #populate the filename field
    self.set( self.filename)
   


#do the processing of the file obtained. Populate the file NAME entry or
#send the filename to the analyzeMFT.py
def processFile(self):       
    arguments = "analyzeMFT.py -f "+self.filename+" -d --bodyfull -l -o "+self.filename+".csv"
    os.system(arguments)

    mftsession.MftSession.process_mft_file(self)

#get and set methods for the entry field
def get(self):
    return self.filename_area.get()

def set(self, value):
    self.filename_area.delete(0, END)
    self.filename_area.insert(0,value)



def main():

  root = Tk()
  root.geometry("450x350+500+500")
  app = Example(root)
  root.mainloop()  


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This method is called by another external script like this

```
mftsession.py


import csv
import json
import os
import sys
from optparse import OptionParser

import mft

 import app
from Tkinter import *
from ttk import *

class MftSession:
"""Class to describe an entire MFT processing session"""

@staticmethod
def fmt_excel(date_str):
    return '="{}"'.format(date_str)

@staticmethod
def fmt_norm(date_str):
    return date_str


def __init__(self):       

    self.mft = {}
    self.fullmft = {}
    self.folders = {}
    self.debug = False
    self.mftsize = 0

def process_mft_file(self):        

    root = Tk()
    appi = app.Example(root)

    self.sizecheck()

    self.build_filepaths()

    # reset the file reading
    self.num_records = 0
    self.file_mft.seek(0)
    raw_record = self.file_mft.read(1024)

    if self.options.output is not None:
        self.file_csv.writerow(mft.mft_to_csv(None, True, self.options))

    while raw_record != "":
        record = mft.parse_record(raw_record, self.options)
        if self.options.debug:
            print record
            appi.print_raw_records_screen(raw_record )  #THIS FUNCTION WHILE INVOKED THIS WAY IS NOT WORKING
            ..........
```

The script analyzeMFT.py called by the app.py through the subrouting

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from os import path

def main(): 


  session = mftsession.MftSession()
  session.mft_options()
  session.open_files()
  session.process_mft_file()



 if __name__ == '__main__':

   if __package__ is None:
        sys.path.append( path.dirname( path.dirname( path.abspath(__file__) ) ) )
    import mftsession
    main()
    
else:
    import mftsession
    main()
```

When called this way it prints nothing to the window, but when i invoke it for testing within its own class it prints the test

```
def print_raw_records_screen(self,records):
    self.area.delete(1.0, "end")
    self.area.insert('1.0', records)
```

and invoke like `print_raw_records_screen("any test"):` in the app.py

[image]

An image can tell alot. and summarize

What am i doing wrong? I sense it's the instantiation am doing wrong. I need diretions please

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey Samuel, Please provide your imports as this may be where part of the problem lies.

Comment: What kind of object does `mft.parse_record()` return?  If it's not a string, it's probably not suitable for inserting into a text field.  Applying `str()` or `repr()` to it might help.

Comment: @jasonharper  I have edited the question and added an image for clarification. Sorry I hadn't provided all the details. Please have a look at it now. Thank you

Comment: @SierraMountainTech  I have edited the question and added an image for clarification. Sorry I hadn't provided all the details. Please have a look at it now. Thank you

Comment: Is your text field in a disabled or readonly state?  That prevents ANY insertion of text, not just user typing.  To use one as an output-only display, you have to temporarily set it back to normal state when inserting your text.

Comment: Well I got it to work on my end. I think its how you are calling the class from the 2nd py file.

Comment: One big problem is I do not have the full code you are using or better yet the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). With the MCVE I could get you a more accurate answer. Please create the MCVE for each py file and update you question. From there I can run a couple test on my end and be able to tell you what it is that is causing the errors.

Comment: @SierraMountainTech you got it to work? What worked? can you please share? And I have edited the question. Added more code to where necessary

Comment: @jasonharper Insertion is okay if and only if i invoke the method inside its own script app.py with test data. So that couldn't be the issue. Thanks for the response

Comment: Hey @jasonharper what other Tkinter widget can be used to hold variety of data types like lists,sets ?

Comment: @SierraMountainTech I have added it. Sorry for the bit by bit questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can see here you have a few issues causing problems.

1. you are importing `app.py` on `mftsession.py` instead importing `mftsession.py` on `app.py`.
2. You are trying to use `appi.print_raw_records_screen(raw_record)` on a completely different instance of the `Example()` class with `appi = app.Example(root)` remove that part all together.
3. It is bad practice to importing inside a function. Import at the start of each py file.

There is so many things going on in your code I had to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of my own to illustrate the relation between files.

Here is a simple example of how the 2 files can interact and the way I think you are trying to do things.

Here I have created a main file called `app.py`:

```
from Tkinter import *
# You might need to import the py file with the package name as well.
# Change the package name to the package your python files are located in.
import PACKAGE_NAME.file_b

class Example(Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.parent = parent
        self.filename = ""        
        analize_button = Button(self.parent, text="Analize",  command=self.processFile)
        analize_button.pack()
        self.area = Text(self.parent, height = 2, width = 40)
        self.area.pack()

    def print_raw_records_screen(self,records):
        self.area.delete(1.0, "end")
        self.area.insert('1.0',records)

    def processFile(self):       
        PACKAGE_NAME.file_b.process_mft_file(self)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = Example(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Here I have created a file called `file_b.py`

```
from Tkinter import *

def process_mft_file(self):        
    record = "Some values assigned to a variable"
    self.print_raw_records_screen(record)
```

The results look something like this:

[image]

Comment: @samuelkungu sorry about that. It was the code used for my side in my test package. I have updated the code to be more accurate.

Comment: got this  mftsession.MftSession.process_mft_fileError: unbound method process_mft_file as first argument (got Example instead

Comment: @samuelkungu I would need to see the full trackback error to be able to help with this.

Comment: Check this please https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1DJIDFn0RU9TFBOc3UxWG1qWGM  image of the traceback error

Comment: I cant while at work sorry. Firewalls prevent google docs here. However I can check when I get home today. I will be home in about 4 hours

Comment: I have instead edited the question and added the screenshot. Hope it's okay

Comment: @samuelkungu its saying on line 92 there is a problem with how you are calling the method. I really cant help unless you show me the code block that contains line 92 of your code.

Comment: @samuelkungu you might benifit here by creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you with my example and build you code up section by section until you find your problem then work on that issues. I think this would be the best option for you.

Comment: Thank you so much for the support. I will definitely folllow your advice. I highly appreciate your efforts. Thumbs up

Comment: @samuelkungu I would like to be more helpful but it is difficult when my python does not support all your imports. So most of what I can do is look at what I think should be going on rather than being able to fully test your code.

Comment: when you get home, you can have a look at this code https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1DJIDFn0RU9dWo5eEZNZjk5Zlk and let me know where the problem is. Am stuck and stuck and stuck. Thank you

Comment: It worked. Exactly as you said it but changed a little bit. Thanks alot.

Comment: @samuelkungu I am glad you were able to work out the bugs :P